# Creating a global ID for every row in multiple tables for notifications

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, schema, social-networking

I'm designing what is essentially an accounting/retailing application for MS SQL Server 2016. I have ~75 core data object types, each in their own respective table (users, organizations, invoices, payments, etc.).

What I need to create is a notification system,

**e.g.** "Steve paid invoice 1234", "Bob purchased product XYZ", etc. What I was going to create was a "notification types" table:

NotificationTypes:

```
id  message
11  "{0} paid invoice {1]"
12  "{0} purchased product {1]" 
...
```

and then have two corresponding tables that store each notification event's info, and then the values for that notification message. So for example for "Steve paid invoice 1234":

NotificationEvent:

```
id  notificationType (FK)   occured
21  11                      2016-01-01 00:00:00
```

NotificationEventValues:

```
id  notificationEvent (FK)  XXXXX
31  21                      (FK reference to Steve in users table)
32  21                      (FK reference to invoice 1234 in invoices table)
```

Now since I can't create generic foreign keys for NotificationEventValues.XXXXX, I was going to have a single 'dataObjects' table that has FK columns for all 75 data types I have, with only one of the 'data type' columns having a value per row.

This way, every instance of a data object in my database has a unique ID I can reference in the notification field - which will mean a huge table given it has a unique ID for basically every row in the other 75 tables. The other downside is it means for every user, invoice, any 'data object', I'm wasting significant amounts of space since space will be reserved for ID references for the other 74 null-valued columns (since they're fixed size IDs and not variable).

**ASK:**
Is there a better way to achieve my 'global' identifier across all the tables? Or a better way to handle the notification system to avoid this problem?

Comment: Don't use global IDs. We did it in one of our bigger projects and wish we didn't.

Comment: What did you use instead to get around it?

Comment: You can't just change a big system. But do you really need the numbers to be unique over the complete DB?

Answer (score 0):

Create triggers in all table that will insert a record in a table say KeyMaster with one column key which will also be the primry key whenever a record is inserted in any table. The value inserted in this table will be in the format _. For example if a record is inserted in user table with id 1 then the record inserted in KeyMaster table will be 'user_1'. Similarly if a record is inserted in invoice table with id 1 then the recor inserted in KeyMaster table will be 'invoice_1'.

In your NotificationEventValues table you will need only three columns id,notificationEvent and key (FK reference to KeyMaster table).

For getting corresponding record you need to write query similar to below:

```
select *
from NotificationEventValues n
inner join users u on 'user_' + u.id = n.key
```